# How to position tooltip regarding to mouse coordinates in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, mouseevent, positioning

I've got a map in Highcharts. When I point on any country I see tooltip bound to it. Sometimes tooltip appears under cursor and hide some information. Is there a way to position tooltip in `positioner` function regarding on mouse coordinates? Or maybe there is existing a more simple approach? I'm doing everything in react environment in options object.

Thanks!

Upd.

To clarify. I don't want to overlap mouse on tooltip. The difficulty is that the area of the country is different and tooltip is shown differently everywhere

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move tooltip position in Highchart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39198173/how-to-move-tooltip-position-in-highchart)

Comment: I think it's not, cause there is just a simple case with line graph. I'm talking about a huge world map, you can move around whole country and tooltip will appear. USA for example has two points. So I can't solve problem with arguments in positioner function, maybe something exist in ```this.chart``` object, but I can't find it :c

Comment: Then you will need to be more specific with your problem and try to share a reproducible example so that others can easily understand what your end goal is.

Comment: Sorry I can't, it's project from my work and I get whole map from library. I can only extend options object, so I literally can't give any example

Comment: Pretty sure you can reproduce a simplified example of it without using the complete map and library of your work ;)

Comment: Okay, maybe I should try, but little bit later :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that my thought was wrong. If I calculate tooltip by mouse coordinates then we always need place it outside our area, otherwise we can overlap tooltip by cursor again. It's too complicated.

I think the easiest way to do this - it's enable flag [followPointer](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.followPointer), which stick tooltip to your cursor.

Comment: You're right, this is the best solution. Bear in mind that `followPointer` is enabled by default in maps and It was hard to understand your issue without any code provided. For the future, please share your config, to get an answer quicker. Regards!